# Android: RecyclerView is not scrolling within CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have custom `LinearLayout` which height can be set to maximum or minimum based on content it holds. But if there is RecyclerView inside this `LinearLayout`, onMeasure is still returning 0 when I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChange()` in order to refresh `RecyclerView` content.

There is like 300 items in `RecyclerView` but `onMeasure` for parent of `RecyclerView` is still measuring 0 height. I need to cap height of `RecyclerView` to certain value which is set on view initialization.

Custom LinearLayout

```
class LinearLayoutWithVariableHeight: LinearLayout {
    companion object {
        var WITHOUT_HEIGHT_VALUE = -1
    }

    private var maxHeight = WITHOUT_HEIGHT_VALUE
    private var minHeight = WITHOUT_HEIGHT_VALUE

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        var measuredHeight = heightMeasureSpec
        val currHeight = getCurrContentHeight()
        try {
            val heightSize: Int
            App.log("LinearLayoutWithMaxHeight: onMeasure curr_height: $currHeight, max: $maxHeight")
            if (maxHeight != WITHOUT_HEIGHT_VALUE && currHeight > maxHeight) {
                App.log("LinearLayoutWithMaxHeight: onMeasure set xy max height")
                heightSize = maxHeight
            } else if (minHeight != WITHOUT_HEIGHT_VALUE && currHeight < minHeight){
                App.log("LinearLayoutWithMaxHeight: onMeasure set xy min height")
                heightSize = min(minHeight, maxHeight)
            } else {
                heightSize = currHeight
            }

            App.log("LinearLayoutWithMaxHeight: onMeasure heightSize: $heightSize")
            measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
            layoutParams.height = heightSize
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        } finally {
            App.log("LinearLayoutWithMaxHeight: onMeasure final: $measuredHeight")
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, measuredHeight)
        }
    }

    private fun getCurrContentHeight(): Int{
        var height = 0
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            val h = child.measuredHeight
            App.log("LinearLayoutWithMaxHeight: getCurrChildHeight: $h")
            if (h > height) height = h
        }

        return height
    }

    fun setMaxHeight(maxHeight: Int) {
        this.maxHeight = maxHeight
    }

    fun setMinHeight(minHeight: Int) {
        this.minHeight = minHeight
    }
}
```

Update:
I tried to make something similar to RecyclerView instead of its parent, it worked well but RecyclerView is not scrollable now:

```
class RecyclerViewWithMaxHeight: RecyclerView {
    companion object {
        var WITHOUT_HEIGHT_VALUE = -1
    }

    private var maxHeight = WITHOUT_HEIGHT_VALUE

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        App.log("RecyclerViewWithMaxHeight: onMeasure")
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST))
    }

    fun setMaxHeight(maxHeight: Int) {
        this.maxHeight = maxHeight
    }
}
```

main_content_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:background="@color/content"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dialog_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dialog_top_corners"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:translationZ="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_bottomsheet_top">

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dialog_main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dialog_top">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dialog_title_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dialog_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/dialog_title_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.app.components.RecyclerViewWithMaxHeight
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/test_item"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/dialog_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

So if I use only this layout above, It is scrolling perfectly. But as this layout is part of bottomsheet which is part of another layout, I have to wrap it with `CoordinatorLayout` and some parent(in this case `FrameLayout`). If I do it, then scrolling of `RecyclerView` is not working. But I'm not sure why it is happening. I need to have this scrolling inside BottomSheet which is logically part of `CoordinatorLayout` because in other case I can't use `BottomSheetBehavior`.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomContentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false">
        ... some other content anchored to top of content below
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

            ... main_content_layout.xml

        </FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` into my `RecyclerView` layout but same result - can't scroll it.

Layou expectation:
[image]

**UPDATE 3**
As I'm going now with `non-NestedScrollView` version using single `RecyclerView` inside `CoordinatorLayout`, I found some issue with touch events.

I can scroll `RecyclerView` if I start to drag it right on boundaries between `RecyclerView` and non-scrollable `View` above. I have to put my finger there specifically to start scrolling. If I do it in the middle of RecyclerView for example, it won't scroll.

Added small `onTouchListener` and indeed its not firing at all if `RecyclerView` is under `CoordinatorLayout`.

```
list.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
                App.log("ListOnTouch -> motionEvent: $motionEvent")
                true
            }
```

I'm not sure why `CoordinatorLayout` is blocking touch events of my `RecyclerView` and why its not blocked right on boundaries between list and other View above.

I've tried to add `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` to `CoordinatorLayout` top-most View (In my case `FrameLayout`) but its not helping  at all.

**UPDATE 4**

Since I possibly found an issue which is causing this weird behavior here is some insight to it.

As I mentioned I'm using this `CoordinatorLayout` to have `BottomsheetBehavior` attached to its top-most child.

As I found out `CoordinatorLayout` is not supporting multiple scrollable children within its top-most child because `BottomsheetBehavior` is working only with 1st scroll child in `View` hierarchy.

I have horizontal `RecyclerView` on top and then vertical one below it.

I made this custom `BottomsheetBehavior` which should handle focus on each `RecyclerView` inside `CoordinatorLayout`.

And its finally working, but I have an issue with scrolling behavior in it:

- If I touch it, it always scrolls my RecyclerView to top and start from there
- If I scroll and lift my finger from touchscreen, it stops scrolling (there is not that generic fast-scroll effect).

I need to solve these issues and it should work correctly.

```
class MultiScrollRecyclerViewBottomsheetBehavior<V : View>(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet
) : BottomSheetBehavior<V>(context, attrs) {

    private var activeRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var coordinatorHeight = 0
    override fun onLayoutChild(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, layoutDirection: Int): Boolean {
        val lp = child.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        if (lp.height == CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
            child.layout(0, parent.height - peekHeight, parent.width, parent.height)
        } else {
            super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection)
        }

        // get the height of the CoordinatorLayout
        App.log("MultiScrollBottomsheetBehavior: onLayoutChild: parent: ${parent.height}")
        coordinatorHeight = parent.height

        return true
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(
        parent: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: V,
        event: MotionEvent
    ): Boolean {
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // Find the topmost RecyclerView that is below the touch point
            activeRecyclerView = findChildRecyclerView(parent, event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, event)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // Forward touch events to the topmost RecyclerView
        return activeRecyclerView?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: super.onTouchEvent(parent, child, event)
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V,
        target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray,
        type: Int
    ) {
        if (type == ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH && state == STATE_EXPANDED) {
            // Forward scroll events to the topmost RecyclerView
            activeRecyclerView?.let {
                if (dy > 0 && !it.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    // If the RecyclerView is scrolled to the bottom and the user tries to scroll further down,
                    // let the default behavior handle the event
                    super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type)
                } else {
                    // Otherwise, forward the event to the RecyclerView
                    it.scrollBy(0, dy)
                    consumed[1] = dy
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recursively searches the [parent] view hierarchy for a [RecyclerView] that contains the given [x] and [y] coordinates.
     */
    private fun findChildRecyclerView(parent: ViewGroup, x: Int, y: Int): RecyclerView? {
        for (i in 0 until parent.childCount) {
            val child = parent.getChildAt(i)
            if (child is RecyclerView && isPointInsideView(x, y, child)) {
                return child
            } else if (child is ViewGroup) {
                val recyclerView = findChildRecyclerView(child, x, y)
                if (recyclerView != null) {
                    return recyclerView
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the given [x] and [y] coordinates are inside the bounds of the [view].
     */
    private fun isPointInsideView(x: Int, y: Int, view: View): Boolean {
        val location = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location)
        val viewX = location[0]
        val viewY = location[1]
        return (x >= viewX && x <= viewX + view.width && y >= viewY && y <= viewY + view.height)
    }
}
```

And I just add it to my top-most parent like this:

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
                app:layout_behavior="com.project.utils.MultiScrollRecyclerViewBottomsheetBehavior">

            </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share illustrations of what u have now and what you want to achieve or even a video mb?

Comment: Why didn't you reply in comments and mention that you have added image?) And saw it only now.  Seems pretty doable, ill try to find some time and try implementing that in coming days.

Comment: Yeah I forgot. Issue with this is only RecyclerView Inside CoordinatorLayout parent. If I remove CoordinatorLayout it works. If I add CoordinatorLayout it doesnt matter if there is only recyclerview as single component or multiple views + RecyclerView, it will not scroll. It has something to do with CoordinatorLayout itself which is blocking scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I have stuck with a similar issue but with `CollapsingToolbar` though maybe the same thing might get applied in it too. Try to do the following changes in your `main_content_layout.xml`

1. Add `NestedScrollBar` having this property
   `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`
   having inner parent layout of your choice.
2. Add this property `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in your `RecyclerView`
   which is inside the Scrollable container for proper scrolling.

Comment: I've tried this already but it didnt work. Items did not recycle in this case. Scrolling worked because I had NestedScrollView but RecyclerView items did not recycle at all which caused app freezes on UI thread during loading

Comment: Look what I have found from the overridden method. 

```/**
             * This specific call should be considered deprecated and replaced with
             * {@link #defaultOnMeasure(int, int)}. It can't actually be replaced as it could
             * break existing third party code but all documentation directs developers to not
             * override {@link LayoutManager#onMeasure(int, int)} when
             * {@link LayoutManager#isAutoMeasureEnabled()} returns true.
             */```
Let me know if it helps you finding the cause.

Comment: Try making layout manager auto measure enabled false and try.

Comment: I've tried it but same result. Its not recycling any views in RecyclerView. I just got spam onCreateViewHolder 200 times as I try to scroll, freezing my entire app in a process